# R and map: how to know the name of each subdivision in a shapefile

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, r-sf

I'm using ggplot and the "sf" package to plot a map of Nepal and its 3983 villages. The village_level map data is a .shp file (similar to what can be found here https://data.humdata.org/dataset/administrative-bounadries-of-nepal). I use

```
nepal_village <- st_read("nepal_village.shp")

village_plot <- ggplot() +
        geom_sf(data = nepal_village) + 
        ggtitle("AOI Boundary Plot") + 
        coord_sf()

village_plot
```

I want to color-code the map with the population of each village. The population is stored in another file, with one column being the name of the village and the other column being the population. Is it possible to merge the population file with the map file? How to get the name of each village in the .shp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to join the datasets via dplyr

```r
join <- dplyr::left_join(x = nepal_village , y = village_pop, by = 'shared column name')
```

I've not worked much with ggplot much for mapping but with tmap you could visualize it as follows.
I'm sure there is a means for visualising it in ggplot as well.

```r
village_plot <- tm_shape(join) + 
    tm_polygon(col= "villagePOP") +
    tm_layout(title = "AOI Boundary Plot")
```

Answer (score 1):

In your .shp (shapefile) you have a column with names of the villages.
Read the shape file to an object (in the the example Austria)

```
austria_shapes <- read_sf("data/gadm36_AUT_shp/gadm36_AUT_1.shp") # in data folder
```

then join with your second table by the village name to object: data_joined.
and then:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = data_joined, aes(fill = n),
          color = "grey", size = 0.15) +
  geom_sf_label(data = data_joined, aes(label = ..your_label_vector.. )) +
  theme_void() + # position matters due to legend bottom
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = 'white', high = 'red') +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.spacing.y = grid::unit(-0.45, "cm"),
        legend.spacing.x = unit(1.0, 'cm'),
        plot.title = element_text(size=22,hjust = 0.5) # title of plot
  ) + # 50 cm equals to 5 cm because of issue #2398
  labs(fill = "whatever you want") +
  geom_point(data = shape_df, 
             aes(x = long, y = lat, group = NULL,fill = NULL, 
                 size = n), color = "green",alpha = I(6/10), 
             show.legend = FALSE) + 
  ggtitle('whatever you want more')
```